# How to solve this star delta problem?

Tags: delta, star

Please help me solve this star delta problem:

[image: Star Delta Transformation question]

---

My attempt:

[image: Attempt at solution]

What to do next to solve this completely?

Comment: It looks like homework so you need to show some effort. You seem to know that you'll need to do a star-delta (or delta-star) transformation so where are you stuck? What do your course notes or your web research tell you? Please [edit] to show your work.

Comment: You've done the hard part. Can you see that you have 12.2 in parallel with 7.4?

Comment: I didn't check the exact numbers, but it looks like you already did the hard part. Maybe a short break will help?

Comment: Yes, I solved it Total Resistance=3.69 ohm

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer and then accept it so the system knows your question is solved. Otherwise it keeps popping up hoping for an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I solved it Total Resistance=3.69 ohm

Comment: This answer isn't going to be much help to anyone with a similar problem.

Comment: The theme is Delta-Star, so instead of taking the easy route, you prudently turned the delta 7, 3.2, 7.4  to a star…